# Angular TypeError: Cannot create property on string '' using Rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

Iam using Angular 11, use rxjs and i wont filter my course collection to course with category equal "frontend". but i got some error

My Code :

```
getPosts():Observable<ICourses[]> {
    return this.http.get<ICourses[]>(`${apiURL}course/getall`).pipe(
      map((courses: ICourses[]) => {
          return Object.values(courses).filter(course => {
            course.devCategory = "frontend"
          })
      })
    )
  }
```

Error :

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot create property 'devCategory' on boolean 'true'
```

Interface ICourses :

```
interface ICourses {
   _id: string
   title: string,
   image: string,
   instructor: string,
   topic: string,
   level: string,
   price: number,
   hours: number,
   students: number,
   category: string,
   devCategory: string,
   created_at: Date,
   updated_at: Date
   date: string
}

export {ICourses}
```

If i use this code :

```
getPosts():Observable<ICourses[]> {
    return this.http.get<ICourses[]>(`${apiURL}course/getall`).pipe(
      map((courses: ICourses[]) => {
          **return courses.filter(course => {
            course.devCategory = "frontend"
          })**
      })
    )
  }
```

I got this error :

```
ERROR TypeError: courses.filter is not a function
```

Comment: have a look to your `ICourses` interface, it looks like you did something like `devCategory: true` instead of `devCategory: string`

Comment: Show interface for "Category". It looks like devCatergory property defined there as boolean

Comment: `course => course.devCategory === "frontend"` the solution for your filter.

Comment: what values courses have?

Comment: It looks to me, that your `course` is not `ICourses` but `boolean`.

Answer (score 3):

This error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot create property 'devCategory' on boolean 'true'
```

says that this line

```
course.devCategory = "frontend"
```

tries to do literally

```
 true.devCategory="frontend"
```

which is obviously not what you want to do.

double check what actually is returned in HTTP response as it looks like it is not `ICourses[]` at all

Answer (score 1):

First of all: For `filter` to work you need to return a boolean value. Also if `courses` already is an array you won't need `Object.values` to filter it:

```js
getPosts(): Observable<ICourses[]> {
  return this.http
    .get<ICourses[]>(`${apiURL}course/getall`)
    .pipe(
      map((courses: ICourses[]) => {
        return courses.filter((course) => course.devCategory === "frontend")
      })
    )
}
```

But you seem to have a problem with your API, because the courses seem to bee `boolean` values not `ICourse` objects.

Comment: i got this error :
ERROR TypeError: courses.filter is not a function

Comment: Yes because your API returns wrong values

Comment: What does this log in the console `.pipe(tap(console.log))`